# How to decode jwt and get from this userId in feathersjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, decode, feathersjs

I'm using Feathers framework to my nodejs application and i have done creation of jwt in following way

```
  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies),
        function (hook) {
         hook.params.payload = {
            userId: hook.params.user.userId,
            accountId: hook.params.user.accountId
          };
          return Promise.resolve(hook);
        }
      ],
      remove: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
      ]
    }
  });
```

now i have doubt how to get userId from token using jwt decoded data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using jwt-decode lib will provide the jwt decode functionality in feathersjs

```
const decode = require('jwt-decode');

hook.params.headers.authorization =  'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImFjY291bnRJZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTA2MzMwNzIyLCJleHAiOjE1MDY0MTcxMjIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8veW91cmRvbWFpbi5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJmZWF0aGVycyIsInN1YiI6ImFub255bW91cyJ9.gZrDJhmzdpt9-7OCeRcKiayQiKbtv-3UaTkN1BhOCAI'

var userId =  decode(hook.params.headers.authorization).userId; 
console.log(userId)
1
```

Comment: Can I known where to do this in src/authentication.js

Comment: in Feathers new version jwt object structure changed and userId changed to sub 

var userId =  decode(hook.params.headers.authorization).sub